# How can I send and process a http request from Visual Basic?

Tags: php, vb.net, vb6

I am playing a web-browser text-based game and I saw that some applications can access my account and do something like upgrade resources, etc., but not cheat.

How these applications can connect to the website and send requests to it?

Comment: These applications just do the same thing as what a macro in your browser would do. They just usually (depending on the design of the site) go much faster because they don't need to render anything and just simulate your clicks.

Comment: As for your question, please try to explain better what you want to do because I don't get it.

Comment: for example i want to connect to google site from my site and write "book" on search box and search it

Comment: What do you want to do of the result? Save it in some string variable? Display it?

Comment: display it,i want to connect to webbrowser game and for example upgrade my resource

Comment: So you want to do this from Visual Basic?

Comment: i saw the application with visual basic and other with php

Comment: http://vb-barnamenevis.ir/warian-manager/tutorial-images/2.jpg

Comment: or this http://vb-barnamenevis.ir/warian-manager/tutorial-images/1.jpg

Comment: I feel this would be too broad for a good answer but here are a couple links that could help you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301102 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Webscraping is prohibited by the terms of service of most sites and is considered prohibited unless explictly permitted.  Google has been known to blacklist entire subnets when such abuse is detected, wiping out the use of Google searches for hundreds of users.

Don't even get started down this road: webscraping is a crime.